# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}2^k=3^n$ using mathematical induction.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Ok so I'm not looking for someone to just straight up tell me the answer but if you could nudge me in some direction approaching a valid proof that'd be great.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}2^k=3^n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (eq.1)$

(1) for $n=1$:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{1}{1 \choose k}2^k = {1 \choose 0}2^0+{1\choose1}2^1 = 1+2 = 3 = 3^1 $$

so eq.1 is true for n=1.

(2) Assume eq.1 holds for $n=p$. That is,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p} {p \choose k}2^k=3^p $$
is a true statement.

(3)  Show that (2) necessitates eq.1 be true for $n=p+1$. That is, show
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1} {p+1 \choose k}2^k=3^{p+1}.$$

So anyhow, I've been attempting to start (3) by splitting the sum from k=0 to p then having the last term separate like so :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1} {p+1 \choose k}2^k=\sum_{k=0}^{p} {p+1 \choose k}2^k+2^{p+1}$$

This is the method the prof suggested but I'm getting nowhere with it.  And yes I *must* use induction.

Comment: Expand the term $p+1$ choose $k$

Comment: @CSchofx: The inductive hypothesis is taken to hold for $n=p$ and you're to show that it holds for $n=p+1$ too to complete the inductive step. Taking $p+1=t$ and using the inductive hypothesis with $n=t$ would just be tacitly assuming the result you're supposed to prove, resulting in circular reasoning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: In order to use your inductive hypothesis, it'd be ideal if we had $\binom{p + 1}{k}$ in terms of $\binom{p}{k}$. As it turns out, there's a recurrence relation called [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule):
$$\binom{p + 1}{k} = \binom{p}{k} + \binom{p}{k - 1}.$$
(If you haven't seen this identity before, it's fun to find a combinatorial proof for it!)

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

(maybe is cheating) You can always use that $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}1^{n-k}2^k=
 (1+2)^n$$